# Number of functions from $ \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\} $ s. t. $|f^{-1}[\{a\}] |= 1$, $|f^{-1}[\{b\}] |= 2$, $|f^{-1}[\{c\}] |= 3$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Let $ A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}. \,$ I need to find the number of functions $ \, f : A \to B \, $ such that there are $ \,  a, b, c \in A \, $ for which $ \, \left|f^{-1}[\{a\}]\right| = 1, \left|f^{-1}[\{b\}]\right| = 2 \, $ and $ \, \left|f^{-1}[\{c\}]\right| = 3$.

Did I do it correctly?

First choose $ 3 $ random elements from $ A $, there are $ {6 \choose 3} $ ways to do so. Arrange the elements in an ordered list: $ a, b, c $ - There are $ 3! $ ways to do that.

For each element, choose its $ f^{-1} $.

$ a: {6 \choose 1} = 6$

$ b: \frac{{5 \choose 2}}{2!} = 5$

$ c: $ automatically chosen.

Therefore, according to the rule of product, there are $ {6 \choose 3}\cdot3!\cdot6\cdot5 $ such functions.

Comment: What are all those absolute value signs in your question? It seems like you don't need them.

Comment: @SuzuHirose it denotes the cardinality of the set

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: I think that this should say $f:A\rightarrow A$ not $B$, there is no definition of $B$.

Comment: Also if $a$ is a subset of $A$ then it should say $a\subset A$.

Comment: @Prem but aren't we supposed to decide which one is $ a $, which one is $ b $, and which one is $ c $?

Comment: @Prem what are these ordered pairs?

Comment: Choosing "b" , it is not necessary to "Divide by 2!" , In other words , it is not 5, but 5x2. It then "matches" the Answer given by @Arnau Mas !

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be fixed elements of $A$ and consider a function $f$ that satisfies the desired property.

First note that, by the pigeonhole principle, every element in $A$ can only be mapped to either $a$, $b$ or $c$. In other words, $f^{-1}(\{a\}) \cup f^{-1}(\{b\}) \cup f^{-1}(\{c\}) = A$ and the union is disjoint. So it is now a matter of counting partitions of this form.

The preimage of $a$ must have one element, so there are 6 possible choices. The preimage of $b$ must have two elements, and it is also disjoint from the preimage of $a$, hence we must make two choices out of the 5 remaining elements in $A$, i.e. ${5 \choose 2}$. Finally the preimage of $c$ must contain three elements and also be disjoint from the preimages of both $a$ and $b$, hence there is no choice to be made since there are only three elements left.

So, for any choice of $a$, $b$, $c$ there are $6 \cdot {5 \choose 2}$ functions from $A$ to itself that satisfy the required property. There are $3!{6 \choose 3} = \frac{6!}{3!}$ possible picks of $a$, $b$ and $c$, since order does matter here. Hence a total of $3! \cdot {6 \choose 3} \cdot 6 \cdot {5 \choose 2}$ functions that satisfy the desired property.

Comment: The binomial coefficient ${5 \choose 2}$ counts number of unordered pairs, so I believe the overcounting is already accounted for. If anything OP undercounts by dividing by $2!$

Comment: You chose which elements are in the image set.  However, you have not chosen which of those three elements is the image of one element, which is the image of two elements, and which is the image of three elements.

Comment: That’s the last step, which gives the factor of ${6 \choose 3}$.

Comment: That is incorrect.  There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to select which three elements are in the image.  You have not accounted for which one is which.

Comment: Yeah you’re right, order does matrer in the choice of $a,b$ amd $c$.

Comment: @Prem This answer is now correct.  The OP's answer is incorrect since there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to select the preimage of $b$, not $5$.

Comment: Oh yes , your contribution to this calculation has made it Correct , @N.F.Taussig